# Strings created in Asynctask wont work in BaseAdapter - Android

Tags: android, string, class, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I have an asynctask that gathers usernames, comments, and numbers and puts them into strings. These Strings are then suppose to be used for a BaseAdapter, but when the BaseAdapter is called it says the String variables are empty. Here is my current code,

```
    public class DashboardActivity extends ListActivity {
     String comments[];
     String usernames[];
     String numbers[];
     ListView lstComments;


    class CreateCommentLists extends BaseAdapter{
            Context ctx_invitation;
            String[] listComments;
            String[] listNumbers;
            String[] listUsernames;


            public CreateCommentLists(Context ctx_invitation, String[] comments, String[] usernames, String[] numbers)
            {
                super();
                this.ctx_invitation = ctx_invitation;
                listComments = comments;
                listNumbers = usernames;
                listUsernames = numbers;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return listComments.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return listComments[position];
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View v = null;
                try
                {
                    String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
                    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)ctx_invitation.getSystemService(inflater);
                    v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                    TextView commentView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listComment);
                    TextView NumbersView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listNumber);
                    TextView usernamesView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listPostedBy);


                    commentView.setText(listComments[position]);
                    NumbersView.setText(listNumbers[position]);
                    usernamesView.setText(listUsernames[position]);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return v;
            }

          }

         final CreateCommentLists mycmlist = new CreateCommentLists(this, comments, usernames, numbers);




        class loadComments extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, JSONObject> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();


            } 

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            } 

            protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {


                JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);


                    return json2;



            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json2) {
                try {  
                    if (json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) { 
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res2 = json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res2) == 1){ 



                            /*JSONArray commentArray = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_COMMENT);
                            String comments[] = new String[commentArray.length()];
                            for ( int i=0; i<commentArray.length(); i++ ) {
                                comments[i] = commentArray.getString(i);
                            }
                            JSONArray numbersArray = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_NUMBER);
                            String numbers[] = new String[numbersArray.length()];
                            for ( int i=0; i<numbersArray.length(); i++ ) {
                                numbers[i] = numbersArray.getString(i);
                            }
                            JSONArray usernameArray = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_USERNAME);
                            String usernames[] = new String[usernameArray.length()];
                            for ( int i=0; i<usernameArray.length(); i++ ) {
                                usernames[i] = usernameArray.getString(i);
                            }*/








                            }//end if key is == 1
                        else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText(json2.getString(KEY_ERROR_MSG));
                        }//end else
                    }//end if
                } //end try

                catch (JSONException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }//end catch    
            }
        }


        new loadComments().execute();

    }
```

Here is my LogCat,

```
    07-16 22:00:05.866: D/AndroidRuntime(10072): Shutting down VM
07-16 22:00:05.866: W/dalvikvm(10072): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ac9228)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at com.example.DashboardActivity$1CreateCommentLists.getCount(DashboardActivity.java:389)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:460)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at com.example.DashboardActivity$1loadComments.onPostExecute(DashboardActivity.java:539)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at com.example.DashboardActivity$1loadComments.onPostExecute(DashboardActivity.java:1)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-16 22:00:05.896: E/AndroidRuntime(10072):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check in constructor of CreateCommentLists, if the comments you pass is null or not. Where are you calling the constructor and are you initialising the data before data in your AsyncTask?
You seem to pass null comments, thats why u get null pointer exception in getCount method of your adapter Change to this
```

@Override

```
      public int getCount() {
if(null == listComments)
{
return 0;
}

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return listComments.length;
            }
```

Comment: I have tried this and it stops of error, but the BaseAdapter is not updating once the Asynctask is done?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize 'comments' and/or give it any data, so it has crashed due to a NullPointerError. When you create the adapter, all the arguments in the constructor must be valid because the adapter is going to call getCount() to figure out how many list items to show.

If you switch from an Array to something like an [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html), you can create an empty list and just add to it at any time.

```
public class DashboardActivity extends ListActivity {
    List<String> comments = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> usernames = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView lstComments;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` is executing asynchronously from the Activity that started it. So while you're activity is being created, and thus the list rendered, your `AsyncTask` may still be loading the comments.

You should initialize your list with an empty adapter or simply, as already suggested, initialize your local variables with empty collections.

Then you can add the data to the list in the `onPostExecute()` method of `AsyncTask` by changing the adapter with `setAdapter()`. In this way you'll be sure to update the `ListView` only when the data are available.

Comment: So what would I set the strings to first then? Would it be comments = 0, usernames = 0, numbers = 0 ?

Comment: Set them to new ArrayList<String>() as another user suggested..